# Making an UI for Libgdx that moves with the camera

Tags: java, user-interface, camera, libgdx, box2d

Im having a box2d screen where you can move the camera around. I want to be able to show a scene2d menu around that screen that moves with the camera. The problem right now is that I have no idea how to do this. The BuildScreen below extends from an AbstractControllerScreen which is a class that implements Screen and uses a ViewScreen and ModelScreen. These matches that of the MVC model. Below is the screen that represents the screen where I want the menu and the box2d area. I apologize in beforehand if there is too much code but this is what I have to work with.

public class BuildScreen extends AbstractControllerScreen{

```
private World world;
private List<BuildPart> ships;


private float r = 70f*BodyConstants.WORLD_TO_BOX;

private Renderable stageRendrable;
private final Stage stage;
private Entity stageEntity;
private InputMultiplexer inputHandler;


public BuildScreen (Nimby game) {
    super(game, new CameraControllerBuild());
    ships = new LinkedList<>();
    World world = new World(Vector2.Zero, true);
    this.world = world;
    inputHandler = new InputMultiplexer();


    stageRendrable = new Renderable() {

        @Override
        public void render(final SpriteBatch batch) {
            Table.drawDebug(stage);

        }

        @Override public void debug(final ShapeRenderer sr) { }
    };

    stageEntity = new Entity() {
        public void update(final float delta, final OrthographicCamera cam) {
            float width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
            float height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
            stage.act(delta);

        }
    };

    stage = new Stage();
    stage.setCamera(getViewScreen().getCam());
    inputHandler.addProcessor(stage);


    Bundle stageBundle = new Bundle(stageEntity, stageRendrable);

    addBundles(stageBundle);
```

//Box2d code omitted//

```
    Bundle b = new Bundle(engine, engine);
    addBundles(b);

    inputHandler.addProcessor(new BuildScreenInputProcessor(world, getCamera(), stage));


    world.setContactListener(new NodeSnapper());
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputHandler);
}

public void resize(int width, int height) {
    getViewScreen().getCam().setToOrtho(false, 1, height / width);
    if (stage != null) {
        stage.clear();
    }

    TextureAtlas atlas = new TextureAtlas("ui/morebuttons.pack");

    Skin skin = new Skin(atlas);
    Table table = new Table(skin);

    table.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
    BitmapFont white = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/terminal.fnt"), false);

    /* Making a button style */ 
    TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("blankbutton");
    textButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("blankbuttonpressed");
    textButtonStyle.pressedOffsetX = 1;
    textButtonStyle.pressedOffsetY = -1;
    textButtonStyle.font = white;
    textButtonStyle.fontColor = Color.BLACK;

    /*Creates button*/
    TextButton newButton = new TextButton("NEW", textButtonStyle);

    table.add(newButton);


    stage.addActor(table);

    getViewScreen().setStage(stage);
}
```

The ViewScreen class, if of any interest looks like this.

public class ViewScreen {

```
private OrthographicCamera cam;
private ShapeRenderer sr;
private SpriteBatch batch;
private List<Renderable> renderables;
private CameraController camControll;
private Stage stage;
private Box2DDebugRenderer d;
/**
 * @return the cam
 */
public OrthographicCamera getCam() {
    return cam;
}

/**
 * @return the camControll
 */
public CameraController getCamControll() {
    return camControll;
}

public ViewScreen(final OrthographicCamera ocam, final CameraController cameraController) {
    this.cam = ocam;
    d = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    renderables = new LinkedList<Renderable>();
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    sr = new ShapeRenderer();

    setCamControll(cameraController);
}

public synchronized void render(float delta) {
    getCamControll().update();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // RENDER SPRITES

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    batch.begin();

    Iterator<Renderable> itr = renderables.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Renderable r = itr.next();
        r.render(batch);
    }

    batch.end();


    if (ModelScreen.world != null) {
        d.render(ModelScreen.world, cam.combined);
    }


    sr.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    sr.begin(ShapeType.Line);
    for (Renderable r : renderables) {
        r.debug(sr);
    }
    sr.end();

    // RENDER GUI
    float camzoom = cam.zoom;
    Vector3 camPos = cam.position.cpy();

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(new Matrix4());
    if (stage != null) {
        batch.begin();

        stage.draw();
        batch.end();
    }




}

public synchronized void add(Renderable renderable) {
    renderables.add(renderable);
}

public synchronized void remove(Renderable renderable) {
    renderables.remove(renderable);
}

public void resize(int width, int height) {
    cam.viewportHeight = height;
    cam.viewportWidth = width;
}

/**
 * @param camControll the camControll to set
 */
public void setCamControll(CameraController camControll) {
    this.camControll = camControll;
}

/**
 * @param stage the stage to set
 */
public void setStage(Stage stage) {
    stage.setCamera(cam);
    stage.setViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), true);

    this.stage = stage;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, that you set the same `cam` to the `stage` and the rest of your game. A libgdx `Stage` has its own `camera`. You should use this, as this `camera` won't move arround. So you have your `camera` and your `SpriteBatch` to render the game and the `Stage`s `cam` and `SpriteBatch` to render the UI over it. Just make sure you call `spriteBatch.end();` before calling `stage.draw()`, because if two SpriteBatches are active it will mess up things.

Comment: Ive implemented a second camera for the class ViewScreen. The problem is where I would use that second camera, because as of currently it now only shows the button but not the box2d world. I dont know how to show both cameras

Comment: Just render your Box2D world with the camera in your viewScreen. You only need 1 camera. Then call stage.draw(). This draws all the Actors on that stage, using the stages camera (you don't need to implement another one Stage allready has one) and with the stages spritebatch. Just make sure you end() the box2d spritebatch before calling stage.draw()

Answer (score 0):

Without dvelving too much into your actual code, I believe the typical usage is something like this:

```
@Override public void resize(int w, h) {
    ... do your regular stuff, including recreating stage if necessary
    stage.setViewport(w, h, false, 0, 0, w, h);
}

@Override public void render(float dt) {
    ... do your normal rendering, then draw ui on top
    stage.draw();
}
```

This should render your UI on top of whatever else you have on screen, and it uses a fixed viewport that covers the whole screen independently of everything else.